# Power BI with animated R visuals

Tags: r, powerbi, bupar

I can output statically generated "png" images from my R code onto Power BI using the "R script visual" function.

Is it possible to output an animated "svg" such as one generated by processanimateR onto my powerbi page:

https://bupaverse.github.io/processanimateR/

I looked into HTML Vizualiser, but it doesn't link with the R script visual function.

Thanks

Comment: Yes, you have to use pbiviz: https://laustep.github.io/stlahblog/posts/pbiviz.html

Comment: Although it is not R, you can use a similar GoG language like Vega to place animated plots in PowerBI. There are multiple examples on my LinkedIn including this one. https://www.linkedin.com/feed/update/urn:li:activity:7004826699401953280/

Comment: @StéphaneLaurent Will the R packages of PowerBI support the development of a visualisation using the module processanimateR? (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/connect-data/service-r-packages-support) Thank you.